# supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource error when hosted online

Tags: php, mysql

The following code works when i run it in localhost, but when I host it online, it gives an error.

```
if(isset($_POST['congressman'])){
    $congressman = $_POST['congressman'];
    $no_of_votes = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT no_of_votes FROM `tbcandidates` WHERE `identification_no`=$congressman"),0) + 1;
    $query=mysql_query("UPDATE tbcandidates SET no_of_votes = '$no_of_votes' WHERE identification_no = $congressman");
```

This line:

```
no_of_votes = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT no_of_votes FROM `tbcandidates` WHERE `identification_no`=$congressman"),0) + 1;
```

It says mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in etc..

Comment: That could mean so much it's almost impossible to help you. I'm guessing (really a shot in the dark) that there's an error occurring somewhere before a `header('Location...')` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add    `ob_start()` at the top of the code and `ob_flush()` at end

Comment: I've added that code on the starting file which is the index.php, do i also have to add that to the 2nd level of user-access?

Answer (score 0):

Headers already sent just means there was already an Data Output before you called that header() instruction...

So you are asking for the reason it is running on localhost while the server denies to run it: Strict modes and error handling - on your webhosts server the settings are probably more strict so errors won't get ignored as on localhost

search for any output made before the header and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the output before the `head` function. It could be some html contents, may be the bom head, or may be some other warning message.

The quick fix is put the code at the top of your script.

```
<?php

if ($_POST['user']=="admin" && $_POST['pass']=="password"){
  header('Location: adminview.php');
  exit;
}
```